# Youtube link parsing in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to parse a youtube link using this code:

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw';
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $parsed_query);
echo '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $parsed_query['v'] . '" type="text/html" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
```

It seems fine if `$url` is hardcoded. But if I add a link using WordPress admin panel, I get an empty variable.

Comment: How are you adding the link in wordpress?

Comment: @RyanLittle im using pods framework. I`m create new post type, and add some new post fields. And using pods template {@video_src} for example

Comment: So, you code it like `$url = {@video_src};` ? or how do you do it?

Comment: @RyanLittle yes, you are right

Comment: I've provided an answer, let me know if that works

Comment: Is it possible to dump url variable into some kind of log while handling admin panel request?

Comment: @AlexanderVasiljev yes, it`s possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way: `$url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_src', true );`

Comment: You missed comma, after first argument).
So look. It works fine, if i use my code in php template file in my theme. But if i using this in pods template, it`s still don`t work

Comment: Thanks, corrected. What do you mean "pods template"?